# What is the 60 30 10 color rule?

Tags: color, website-design, branding, graphic-styles, website-templates

What is the 60 30 10 color rule for website?
How to choose the best color scheme for your website?

Comment: There is no such thing as best color scheme. If there was you wouldn't see any other schemes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=60+30+10+color+rule